# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, send, channel

Not sure what the issue is but help is appreciated!

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = CHANNEL_ID
    isbot = message.author.bot
    if isbot:
        pass
    else:
        await channel.send(message.content)
```

`CHANNEL_ID`is already defined on my `tokens.py`

This issue occurs whenever I send a message in the channel that the bot is focused on.

Comment: Looks like `channel`, which = `CHANNEL_ID` is an `int`, i.e. it's a number, so it doesn't have a `.send` method at the moment - was CHANNEL_ID supposed to be a class?

Comment: Yeah it was supposed to be a class.

Comment: Cool, so you just need to make sure you pass that through then.

Comment: Alright sounds good

Comment: How did you define `CHANNEL_ID` though?

Comment: Using a discord channel ID but this is a error on my part.

Comment: Yeah you have to just get the physical channel from the guild and then send. ID's in discord.py are usually `int`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assigning `channel` to `CHANNEL_ID`, `channel` will be the same data type as `CHANNEL_ID`. Since `CHANNEL_ID` is probably an `int`, you can use a variety of available functions and methods to get the `TextChannel` object to use the `send()` method.

---

Using the `discord.utils.get()` function:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, id=CHANNEL_ID)
    isbot = message.author.bot
    if isbot:
        pass
    else:
        await channel.send(message.content)
```

---

Using the [`Client.fetch_channel()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    isbot = message.author.bot
    if isbot:
        pass
    else:
        await channel.send(message.content)
```

---

Using the [`Client.get_channel()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = await client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    isbot = message.author.bot
    if isbot:
        pass
    else:
        await channel.send(message.content)
```